# shell script to extract text from a variable separated by forward slashes

Tags: shell, awk, cut

I am trying to find a way to to extract text from a variable with words separated by a forward slash. I attempted it using `cut`, so here's an example:

```
set variable = '/one/two/three/four'
```

Say I just want to extract `three` from this, I used:

```
cut -d/ -f3 <<<"${variable}"
```

But this seems to not work. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? Or is there a way of using AWK to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the spaces before and after to `=` during string or variable assignment. And tell the cut command to print the 4th field.

```
$ variable='/one/two/three/four'
$ cut -d/ -f4 <<<"${variable}"
three
```

With the delimiter `/`, cut command splits the input like.

```
             /one/two/three/four
            |  |   |    |    |
            1  2   3    4    5
```

that is, when it splits on first slash , you get an empty string as first column.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main problem here is in your assignment. Try this:

```
var='/one/two/three/four'
cut -d/ -f4 <<<"$var"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
awk -F\/ '{print $4}' <<< "$variable"
three
```

or

```
echo "$variable" | awk -F\/ '{print $4}'
three
```

PS to set a variable not need for `set` and remove spaces around `=`

```
variable='/one/two/three/four'
```